# Why asset:install doesn´t copy /Resources/public to /web folder?

Tags: php, symfony, assets

I'm having an issue running `php app/console asset:install` command. My OS is Windows.

My intention is to copy the css, js, images, etc, files from `app/Resources/public` by using that command. After I run the command, a **bundles** folder is created in `/web`. But in the created bundles folder there aren't any of the files from `app/Resources/public`. Only two folders: **sensiodistribution** and **framework**.

Why don't I get my AppBundle folder with the copied assets in `/web/bundles`?

Answer (score 6):

Your Resource > public folder must be under you bundle or application not under your app folder, you can add twig files to app/resource folder to override (default) files like we do it to override error page, but not for  assets, i tried it didn't work.

[image: like this]

then it will work, you can check this here - [link](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-smarter-assets-install-command)

and it will be better if you use symlink instead of coping folders / files

```
php app/console assets:install --symlink
```

Comment: what Symfony version are you using? The symfony_demo 2.7 I tried doesn't have the Resources/public in the AppBundle. It comes with an assets folder in the app/Resources folder. I don't understand this. Is one of this two ways wrong or both are possible? I can't use --symlink because I have Windows OS. Thanks for your answer

Comment: i am using same version and i added that resource folder for you to display, for your project you have to add assets in your bundle. If you edit base.html.twig file from app/resource/view , you can see that symfony team added css file to line 25 and added other assets before that (commented) and there css/ js file is already in web folder at time of installation that's why it's working, if you delete or rename css folder from web directory then application will not get css, how many time you run assets:install.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I did understand it now. I did what you explained in your answer and it worked. I have to run assets:install every time I update a .js or .css file because I can not use --symlink on Windows. Do you know if there is a way to do something similar so I don't have to use assets:install everytime? @user5419232

Comment: @nessy_ftv just run `php app\console assets:install --symlink` in an administrator CMD

Comment: I recommend following the official symfony best practices instead of storing your assets in a bundle. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 6):

`app/console assets:install` only installs assets that are found in bundles. `app/Resources` is not considered a bundle, so those assets are not being installed.

The Official Symfony Best Practices actually recommend to [store public assets (such as CSS stylesheets, JavaScript files, images, etc.) directly in the `web/` directory](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/best_practices/web-assets.html). As you can see on that page, this also makes it easier to use the assets in your templates.

The purpose of the `app/console assets:install` command is to copy or symlink assets, that are downloaded to your `vendor/` directory as part of third-party bundles, to your public `web/` directory. A good example is the debug toolbar.

However, your own assets are already part of your project, so you can just as easily store them directly in the `web/` directory. There is no benefit in storing them in the `app/Resources` directory in order to copy them to `web/` in a seperate step.

Of course, if you have source files (such as SCSS files or un-minified CSS/JS files), you might not want to store them in a public directory. In that case, use `app/Resources` to store the source files and use a build tool such as Assetic to copy the minified / processed assets to the `web/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
        use_controller: false
        bundles:        [ AppBundle ]

php app/console cache:clear

php app/console assets:install web

php app/console assetic:dump --force
```

Comment: This didn't work for me @rommct. I get RunTimeException when I'm dumping my assets. `The source file C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos\squash_connection\app/../web/js/jquery.js` does not exist

Comment: Check if your file jquery.js exist into your src/AppBundle/Resources/public/js/ directory

Comment: My jquery.js exist into that source. I didn't manage to make this work but I managed in the other way. Thank you very much for your answer.